# Elementary inequality involving modulus

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Is is true that
$$\lvert a+b\rvert^2\geq (\lvert a\rvert-\lvert b\rvert)^2, \quad \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R} ?$$
Is there any related result, related to this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a+b|=|a-(-b)|\geq |a|-|-b|=|a|-|b|$. (I assume you've already proved $|x-y|\geq |x|-|y|$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$)